# Arabic dataframe to pdf using python

Tags: python, jupyter, fpdf

basically, I want a code that converts Arabic dataFrame to a pdf file
when I use this code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas.plotting import table


fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
the_table = ax.table(cellText=report.values,colLabels=report.columns,loc='center')

pp = PdfPages("foo.pdf")
pp.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
pp.close()
```

it export it but with empty cells

Comment: Would setting the font be sufficient? Are you having issues with unicode characters?  Does either https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/index.html or https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_font/index.html help?

Comment: i did it but the Arabic letters are upside down

Comment: Possibly related: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/arabic-pdf-characters-are-disjointed-and-reversed/m-p/4546661 @hesham-ibrahim Please update the question with as much detail as you can on what you've tried and what the results were. This is one of the (few) places where screenshots of the output are appropriate. Please also add relevant references you've found.

Comment: @SarahMesser the problem was when I need to type مرحبا in pdf but the pdf will be     ا ب ح ر م but I found the solution and typed it in the answer, thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that can make Arabic letters display in the pdf

```
#the libraries I used
from fpdf import FPDF
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import subprocess

def arabic_text (text): #function to change مرحبا to ابحرم (will make fpdf read it)
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    return bidi_text

pdf = FPDF() #call FPDF
# I downloaded it from this URL https://arbfonts.com/noto-sans-arabic-regular-font-download.html
pdf.add_font("NotoSansArabic", style="", fname="NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf",uni=True) #add the font
pdf.add_page() #add page
pdf.set_font('NotoSansArabic', '', 8) # set font
pdf.set_xy(5, 5) #set x and y
pdf.cell(0, 0, arabic_text("مرحبا"), align='c') #the word i want to type
try:
    pdf.output('hi.pdf', 'F') # get the pdf file
    subprocess.Popen(['hi.pdf'], shell=True) #open it
except:
    print("Close the pdf file") #message if the pdf is opened
```